# How to set bitmap image center in given position

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

When I set a bitmap image to canvas with x and y coordination.Top left conner of bitmap set to that position.How to center bit map in that coordination.I want to set centre point of image to that coordination.is there any method to do that in android?

This is how i draw bitmap in canvas

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, point_x.get(i), point_y.get(i), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BitmapFactory.Options` to get the dimensions of your bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.bmp, options);
int height = options.outHeight;
int width = options.outWidth;
```

I used a bitmap from resources here as an example. You can find other posibilities here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Then use these dimensions to calculate where the upper left corner should be:
Also set inJustDecodeBounds back to false before loading the bitmap.

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.bmp, options), point_x.get(i) - width/2, point_y.get(i) - height/2, null);
```

Comment: i get token "inJustDecodeBounds", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token error

Comment: @heshjse I have edited the last piece of code. If there are still problems, please post your code.